# React SSR get hostname

Tags: reactjs, express, redux, redux-saga

I have written an app with express, React, Redux, Redux-saga. My app has multiple domains and depending on the domain, the user gets their own site. 
When I want to show users site, I need to call an API to get site property. For calling the API I need hostname.
In Express 'app.get', I can get the hostname from request parameter that defines in app.get middleware. How can I get the request hostname in React?

This is How I get it in Express:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log('req.hostname : ', req.hostname);
 next();
});
```

Comment: window.location.hostname ?

Comment: @MartinKadlec on the server window object is undefiend

Comment: Oh, so you are talking about rendering React on server? Then, assuming you are rendering the React on the request, you can take the hostname and pass it to ReactDOMServer props. If you don't render the React immidiately on the request but sometime later you might want to store it in a session/instance.